# Incorrect free space RAID 5 on Asustor AS1004T

Tags: linux, filesystems, raid, raid-5, asustor

I have an Asustor AS1004T NAS with 3 WD Red 3TB's in RAID 5. (WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 in case anyone cares). This gives me a total volume size of 5.36TB.

Recently one of the WD's became faulty and I RMA'd it and put in a spare WD Red I had lying around. Added that into the RAID array and now I have a healthy RAID again. Or so it seems.

The volume is showing as having 239TB free of 5.36TB.

In windows:

[image: Wrong size displayed in Windows]

In the Asustor ADM interface:

[image: Wrong size displayed in ADM]

This is the output of  `df -Th; cat /proc/mdstat`:

```
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs          tmpfs  250M   12K  250M   1% /tmp
/dev/md0       ext4   2.0G  352M  1.5G  19% /volume0
/dev/loop0     ext4   951K   13K  918K   2% /share
/dev/md1       ext4   5.4T -235T  240T    - /volume1
cgroup         tmpfs  250M     0  250M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md1 : active raid5 sdd4[3] sdb4[4] sdc4[1]
      5851357184 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]

md126 : active raid1 sdd3[6] sdb3[7] sdc3[4]
      2095104 blocks super 1.2 [4/3] [UU_U]

md0 : active raid1 sdd2[6] sdb2[4]
      2095104 blocks super 1.2 [4/2] [UU__]

unused devices: <none>
```

As you can see the /dev/md1/ volume does indeed look messed up.

How can I fix this?

Additional information which may be useful: It was a while ago but I seem to remember that I put the drives back in the 'wrong' order (not their original slot) during the process. But the NAS didn't seem to mind and it still recognised the drives with their original RAID drive number. I put them back in the correct order later but this does feel like it could be related to the problem.

Is there some Linux shell magic that I could do to make it re-check the free space and register it correctly again?

Comment: And what filesystem are you using in the md1 device? The filesystem, not the RAID, is where space accounting is performed.

Comment: @user1686 it's ext4, I've updated the question

Comment: Make sure your backups are up to date. That doesn't look good.